# Socket cannot receive all message in localhost between C++ and python

Tags: python, c++, sockets

I am trying to send some floating array(66 elements) from C++ to python in localhost in a speed of 30arrays/sec

here is my C++ client

```
int r;
char message[200];
WSAData wsaData;
WORD DLLVersion;
SOCKADDR_IN addr;
int addlen;
SOCKET sConnect;


DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
r = WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData);
addlen = sizeof(addr);
sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);// IPv4  TCP
int yes = 1;
setsockopt(sConnect, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&yes, sizeof(int));//1 on 0 off Nagle buffering
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address);
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(port);

int result = connect(sConnect, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
if (result == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cout << "Fail to connect!" << endl;
    exit(0);
}
```

And for each iteration, I send data like this

```
send(sConnect, &string_data[0], 66*sizeof(float), 0);
```

And at my python server

```
import socketserver
import numpy as np

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

   def handle(self):
     counter=0
     temp=np.zeros(66)
     while(1):
       self.data = self.request.recv(264).strip()
       temp=np.fromstring(self.data,dtype=np.float32)
       print(counter)
       counter +=1
```

each time when I receive a new data, the counter will be printed out
but it will showing

> string size must be a multiple of element size

and stopping at the iteration which is not always the same
that said
sometime it will stop at counter number 14
or maybe 2
or others

Is it because I send too fast? but  I already enable TCP_NODELAY at client
How do I fix this problem?
or are there better way to send such big amount of data?

Comment: What is `len(self.data)`? I think recv() might return a short read, like it can in C. Maybe you can use a more high level function that don't return until 264 bytes is read.

Comment: I didn't initialize  its length. But since the data i send are 66 floating data, which in total 264 bytes, so i also request a receiving length of 264 bytes.